# I have a problems with dotnet folder

Tags: entity-framework

I wrote a project, I ran cmd, to connect my codes to SQLserver. when I typed dotnet ef migrations add...; It said : that it can't find this 3.1.1 version folder despite the fact that when I asked the version, it would say it is 3.1.1 version.
So i downloaded the 3.1.1 sdk from Microsoft website, I installed it and nothing changed, the 3.1.1 folder wasn't added. I tried to find the folder but I could not.
Suddenly out of nowhere, I decided to download the framework instead. I opened it and it didn't need installation. I just copied this framework and replaced it with the whole dotnet folder which I had problems with. The problem started there, again I executed cmd and wrote dotnet ef... It said there is no ef. I again replaced the framework with another one, it said wrong machine, one another time and it said the dotnet image doesn't fit my pc or sth like this. I uninstalled the dotnet and installed it again, it now says an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. I searched this error, they said I should change the 64bit iis to 32bit. I tried but I can't. Iis manager doesn't have the enable 32 bit option for me! And in the other ways folders are missing.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by first deleting the dotnet folder, then reinstalling visual studio.
Then I downloaded the dotnet sdk for runtime which is suitable for my computer